# How to check if a generic parameter is serializable in an ArchUnit test?

Tags: java, reflection, archunit

I want to write an ArchUnit test to check that all fields in serializable classes are either static, transient, or are Serializable. This means that for all non-primitive types, I have to check if they implement serializable (recursively if these fields are of a non-primitive type).

For collections, I want to check their generics if they are serializable because the serializability of collections depends on this.

So far my rule is laid out like this:

```
fields().that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().implement(Serializable.class)
        .should().beStatic().orShould().haveModifier(JavaModifier.TRANSIENT)
        .orShould(new SerializableCondition()).check(classes);
```

where `SerializableCondition` implements `ArchCondition` with the following condition:

```
private boolean isSerializable(JavaClass javaClass) {
      if (javaClass.isPrimitive()) {
        return true;
      }

      // Recursively check if array components are serializable
      if (javaClass.isArray()) {
        return isSerializable(javaClass.getComponentType());
      }

      // This check does not work as expected
      if (javaClass.isAssignableTo(Collection.class)) {
        var x = ((ParameterizedType)
            javaClass.reflect().getGenericInterfaces()[0])
            .getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        return x instanceof Serializable;
      }

      return javaClass.isAssignableTo(Serializable.class);
    }
```

Obviously, I would like the check for collections to be recursive just like the array one, but right now I want to get it working for simple cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it's neither obvious from your question how you use your `isSerializable` from your `SerializableCondition` (probably somehow by evaluating it on the tested `JavaField`'s `rawType`?), nor what *`// This check does not work as expected`* means exactly, but I would try something like this:

```java
ArchRule rule = fields()
    .that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().implement(Serializable.class)
    .should().beStatic()
    .orShould().haveModifier(JavaModifier.TRANSIENT)
    .orShould(ArchConditions.be(DescribedPredicate.describe("serializable",
        field -> isSerializable(field.getType())
    )));

static boolean isSerializable(JavaType type) {
    JavaClass rawType = type.toErasure();
    return rawType.isPrimitive()
        || rawType.isArray()
            && isSerializable(rawType.getComponentType())
        || rawType.isAssignableTo(Collection.class)
            && type instanceof JavaParameterizedType
            && isSerializable(((JavaParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments().get(0))
        || rawType.isAssignableTo(Serializable.class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. My problem was that `isSerializable` took in a `JavaClass` instead of a `JavaType`, so I couldnt cast it to a `JavaParametrizedType`.